# How to click on copy button with cypress

Tags: copy, cypress, copy-paste

So in my app i have a button and when i click on it, it will save some text into my clipboard, then i can past it by ctrl+v somewhere.

And i am trying to write cypress test for this. Problem is, when i click on that button i got cypress error:

[image]

I can´t figured out. Element is clearly viewed on page. I tryied to wait few second before clicking and it didn´t help.

Is there a way how to test it?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It looks like your website throws an uncaught exception when you do the copy functionality. If you open the developer console in your browser and do the copy functionality, does it register an exception?

Comment: @agoff No, when i click on that button (even in cypress window) everything works fine.

Comment: You can try adding `.focus()` before `.click()`, but I suspect that is already done by `.click()` internals.

Comment: @fody .focus() not work, cypress tell me that "Element is not focusable", i don´t know the err message for 100% but i had classicly cy.get('styled div with copy action').focus().click()  (eventually) .click({force : true})

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so. The "Document not focused" message seems (from other questions) to be related to clipboard activity. Do you have access to the source code, if so what is the click handler code?

Comment: I solved it by catching up exception and by using realClick() from real event library and allowing chrome copy and paste protocol and using clipBoardy library for cypres...

Answer (score 1):

Your application has thrown an error, not cypress. To avoid this, you will want to add this either to your test file or /support/index.js. This code was pulled from this [example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__errors). [Remember `cy.` requires a test or a hook to work, while `Cypress.` does not.](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__cy-events)

```
// inspect the caught error
cy.on('uncaught:exception', (e) => {
  if (e.message.includes('Things went bad')) {
    // we expected this error, so let's ignore it
    // and let the test continue
    return false
  }
  // on any other error message the test fails
})
```

Comment: looks interesting, thanks for your answer

Comment: but i would like to not switch off the errors, they can be useful in other situations... If it will be only one way that i wil have to do it... but i will try to find another solutions.

Comment: even if i switch off these error, cypress is not able to copy it. And it is pasting old values which i have already in clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions globally by writing this under `cypress/support/index.js`

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```